# Nature of Sabre pre-cooler demonstration test

Tags: rockets, engines, sabre-engine

Inspired by a comment to this question "[How does the Sabre engine's pre-cooler achieve such high performance?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26689/how-does-the-sabre-engines-pre-cooler-achieve-such-high-performance)": the comment was that Reaction Engines have demonstrated that the pre-cooler works on a test stand.

Question: In what way was the test representative of the intended altitude and vehicle velocity conditions and what shortfalls, if any, are unavoidable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [2012](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ciCI912YhEg), the precooler was tested at ambient temperature/pressure (there have been lots more test runs, but this one was well-publicized and there's video).

In the summer of 2018, [the precooler will be tested at 1000 ºC](https://www.reactionengines.co.uk/sabre/htx) inlet conditions (comparable to the conditions at Mach 5), using a [J79 engine](https://thespaceport.us/forum/topic/45388-sabre-dual-mode-rocket-engine-reaction-engines-ltd-uk-updates/) from an F-4 as a hot air source.

> The HTX test programme is a manufacturing and performance ground level demonstration of a pre-cooler type heat exchanger in a high enthalpy (temperature) environment, similar to that expected to be seen by the SABRE engine during its air-breathing flight regime – up to ~1000°C air inlet temperature.
>
> The pre-cooler is designed to absorb over 5 megawatts of heat energy from the incoming hot air passing through it so that the outlet air temperature is just above ambient.

Comment: Reaction Engines have tested have tested lab-scale precoolers (a few inches) across high temperature ranges, but the full size ones have only been tested at ambient temperatures using liquid nitrogen as a heat sink. The purpose of the 2012 tests was primarily to demonstrate the frost control.