# What might be the way in which the pre-cooler of the SABRE engine removes water from the inlet air?

Tags: sabre-engine

In [this paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20110725042437/http://www.reactionengines.co.uk/downloads/Heat%20exchanger%20development%20at%20REL%20IAC%2008%20C4.5.2.pdf) about the SABRE engine, there is the following paragraph (emphasis mine):

> The  water  vapour  in  the  atmosphere  up  to  an altitude  of  around   12   km  is  a  problem  for precooled  engines,  causing  them  to  block  with frost in a matter of seconds. A great deal of **this water  is  precipitated  in  the  liquid  phase  during the cooling of the air and has to be rejected from the  engine  before  it  can  freeze**.  Provision  then has to be made to stop the build up of ice within the  matrix  as  it  precipitates  directly  from  the vapour.   A   major   part   of   the   experimental program  has  been  to  demonstrate  that  this  can be achieved.

How might this be achieved? If there is more than one possibility, is there a most likely or an easiest way of doing this?

This should be seen as more of a brainstorming question than as an opinion-based one. After all, Reaction Engines was most secretive about the mechanism, so there will probably not be a definitive, public answer any time before 2013.

Comment: Related https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26689/how-does-the-sabre-engines-pre-cooler-achieve-such-high-performance

Comment: It is explained, in great detail, in patent GB2519153, also published as US patent [US20150101334A1](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20150101334A1/en?oq=20190284998#p-0229) TL;DR: [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/39924/20636) has the jist of it.

Comment: You might also care to look at how it was achieved for Bond's previous air breathing hydrogen rocket engine, "Swallow" (or Rolls-Royce RB545) -- Due to this method being declared an Official Secret  by Her Majesty's Government he had to come up with a different solution for SABRE, as in several other areas the one he came up with was better than the old one.

Comment: @JCRM The more I read about him, the more fascinated I am. Will check out the documentary on him at some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to an article in the July 20, 2015 issue of Aviation Week, they spray methanol into the precooler to defrost it.

> "We inject the methanol at one of the coldest points and we
>   effectively get the mixture of water and methanol to flow forward in
>   the matrix - against the direction of the airflow.... We have multiple injection and removal points in the matrix....Eventually you end up with a situation where you have extracted all the water vapor as liquid from the airflow."

-- Reaction Engines Chief Engineer Richard Varvill as quoted in the article

[image]

Available in the [archive](https://archive.aviationweek.com) but may be paywalled

h/t to [JCRM](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/20636/jcrm) who provided a link to the US [patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20150101334A1/en?oq=20190284998#p-0229) which has additional detail.

Comment: Interesting... is the methanol a consumable which must be re-provisioned for each flight, or is there some sort of recovery cycle for it?

Comment: TL;DR: In Skylons A-C it would be a consumable, in LAPCAT it would be topped up (probably after each flight). In more detail @AnthonyX, paragraph 238 the patent suggests the methanol/water could be added back into the airflow and could add 2% to the thrust, in those cases where losing the weight of the methanol is desirable, thus making it a consumable, and paragraph 245 discusses separating the methanol to reduce the total weight of methanol carried, but that would be at the cost of the permanent weight of the distillation (or other) equipment.